# How to avoid change effective UID while executing files by ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

Background:

I have an executable c++ built program called `UlimitUnlimiter`. Currently, It produce some issues while executing on one of my server.

```
./UlimitUnlimiter
UlimitUnlimiter: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by UlimitUnlimiter)
/UlimitUnlimiter: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by UlimitUnlimiter)
```

This is a Dynamic c++ library issue, and I have another lib path in my package path. Generally, Giving a `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or run it by `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` can solve the problem.

But my case is a little complicated. I setup `setuid bit` for the executable program.

```
chown root:mygroup UlimitUnlimiter
chmod ugo+rx UlimitUnlimiter
chmod +s UlimitUnlimiter
```

And inside the program, it will check if `uid != 0 && gid != 0 && euid == 0`
For a succeed execution, it should be:

```
./UlimitUnlimiter
[UlimitUnlimiter]: uid=10254388
[UlimitUnlimiter]: gid=100
[UlimitUnlimiter]: euid=0
service running...
```

But because of `chmod +s`, running with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will fail even with `expert LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=correct_path_to/lib ./UlimitUnlimiter
UlimitUnlimiter: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by UlimitUnlimiter)
/UlimitUnlimiter: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by UlimitUnlimiter) 


export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=correct_path_to/lib
./UlimitUnlimiter
UlimitUnlimiter: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by UlimitUnlimiter)
/UlimitUnlimiter: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by UlimitUnlimiter)
```

The only way, I can setup the lib path is running by `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, however it will break the `effective user`.

```
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path correct_path_to/lib ./UlimitUnlimiter
[UlimitUnlimiter]: uid=10254388
[UlimitUnlimiter]: gid=100
[UlimitUnlimiter]: euid=10254388
[UlimitUnlimiter]: ulimitunlimiter must be setuid and run by non-root
```

So I am wondering, is there a way that I can both setting up the dynamic lib and not breaking the `setuid bit` at the same time?

Comment: Does setting the path with `-L` at build time instead of with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` work any better?

Comment: Setuid executables should be avoided in general.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Sometimes they're necessary, and this seems like it might be one of those times.

Comment: `-L` sets the compile time path, which won't help. Use `-Wl,-R` to set the runtime path instead. No idea why this is so intent on avoiding `sudo` though